# How do i call the API once and how do i fetch different content from the same API in the context of Vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js, templates

I am new to Vuejs, i am calling different API's in order to fetch the contents, the different API's are same but differs in endpoint.

Here s how i did it:

```
<template>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="First content">
      {{data1}}
    </div>
    <div class="Second content">
      {{data2}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      data1: [],
      data2: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$http.get('/serverdata/3')
      .then((response) => { this.data1 = response.data })
      .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
    
      this.$http.get('/serverdata/4')
      .then((response) => { this.data2 = response.data })
      .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })

  }
}
</script>
```

My question is, how i can have only one API instead of having two. My API is: /serverdata/(only ID is changing). I know that props can be used, but i want to know how it is used within the Vue component and reuse any variable.

If suppose only one API is used as /server/ + id, i want to know how to specify the id in template in order to display the content of the particular id.

Please do help me with this small doubt because i dint find any useful information in the web. Please send me the modified code or example to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple calls to the same endpoint and only the `id` changes, you can write a method which takes in the `id` and the `prop` where it needs to place the result, like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () => ({
    data1: [],
    data2: []
  }),
  created () {
    [ // add your calls to this array...
      [3, 'data1'],
      [4, 'data2']
    ].forEach(payload => this.fetchData(...payload));
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData(id, prop) {
      this.$http.get(`serverdata/${id}`)
        .then( r => this[prop] = r.data)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="First content">
      {{data1}}
    </div>
    <div class="Second content">
      {{data2}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Depending on how similar the responses are, you might be able to streamline the template code (perhaps use a `v-for`). But that's a speculation. You've given no context so far.

You can go further and also remove the `data` prefix in the model properties (assuming all props are prefixed with `data`), changing it to:

```
[[3, 1], [4, 2]].forEach(payload => this.fetchData(...payload));
```

and changing the method to:

```
fetchData(id, prop) {
  this.$http.get(`serverdata/${id}`)
    .then( r => this[`data${prop}`] = r.data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

...but that would be overengineering it.

What I mean by that is that any developer (including yourself, in 6 months from now) looking at this code will spend more time understanding it. And that's actually bad. Always try to write code that's as easy to read/understand as possible. That should be your primary goal. It's a lot more important than it seems.
When you write readable code you're reducing the time you (or others) need to spend modifying it, when they need to. So you're directly saving your company money. That's why code readability is one of the first criteria considered when assessing someone's coding skills.

Comment: @Dan this might workout for me, but as you said its not a good way to do it.